# What would be the closed form of $n\cdot n + (n-2)\cdot(n-2) + (n-4)\cdot(n-4) + \dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

As part of solving [this problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PCJ18B) , I came up with the following expression:

$$\text{ans} = n\cdot n + (n-2)\cdot (n-2) + (n-4)\cdot (n-4) + \dots$$

So I am just running a loop to calculate the ans. However, since there is a pattern in the form of a series, I am wondering if a closed form exists for it? Please also show the steps to obtain so that I can learn, in general, how to approach such problems for finding closed forms.

EDIT: series goes till 2 if n is even, and till 1 if n is odd.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of the first $m$ squares?

Comment: yes, n(n+1)(2n+1)/6. Ok, I got it. This is exactly a standard square sum sequences. How stupid I am. Thanks.

Comment: It would be more amazing to compute $\sum_{k=0}^p (n-2k)^2$ for $p\leq \frac n2$. The formula is nice

Comment: Where exactly does it stop?

Comment: @user3243499: no, it's the sum of the squares of the same parity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: thanks for pointing it out. I was wondering why it is not working when I directly applied the even squared sum formula, and odd squared sum formula.

Comment: @user3243499 Anyway, if you don't explain where it stops, the answer could be anything.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier till 2 if even, 1 if odd. Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well known that the sum of terms that are a polynomial expression of degree $d$, evaluated at the integers, is a polynomial expression of degree $d+1$.

So if you consider four values of the sum, you can obtain the requested expression as the Lagrangian interpolation polynomial on these four points.

For even $n$,

$$(0,0),(2,4),(4,20),(6,56)\to\frac{n^3+3n^2+2n}6.$$

For odd $n$,

$$(1,1),(3,10),(5,35),(7,84)\to\frac{n^3+3n^2+2n}6.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even, you have

$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}2}(2k)^2&=4\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}2}k^2\\
&=4\cdot\frac{\frac{n}2(\frac{n}2+1)(2\cdot\frac{n}2+1)}6\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6 \\
\text{If $n$ is odd, you have} \\
\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n+1}2}(2k-1)^2&=4\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n+1}2}k^2-4\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n+1}2}k+\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n+1}2}1 \\
&=4\cdot\frac{\frac{n+1}2(\frac{n+1}2+1)(2\cdot\frac{n+1}2+1)}6-4\cdot\frac{\frac{n+1}2(\frac{n+1}2+1)}2+\frac{n+1}2 \\
&=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the classic formula for the sum of increasing squares and some manipulation to find:

$$\frac{1}{3} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right) \left(2 \left\lfloor
   \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right) \left(2 \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor
   +3\right)$$

Comment: I don't think that the formula is right for the even $n$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

Let's call the sum of alternate squares up to $n$ by $s(n)$.iafor $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ is

$0,1,4,10,20,35, 56$

The differences between these terms are:

$1,3,6,10,15,21$

which are the triangular numbers $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. So this suggests that

$s(n) = \sum_{m=0}^{n} \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$

$= \sum_{m=0}^{n} (\frac{m^2}{2} + \frac{m}{2})$

$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12} + \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$

$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1) + 3n(n+1)}{12}$

$ = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$

This is *not* a formal proof, but it does suggest a formula which can form the starting point of a proof by induction

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2=\frac{x(x+1)}2+\frac{(x-1)x}2$, your sum becomes $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}2=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6$$